# Error using Selenium Webdriver headless

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using a chrome Webdriver to take a screenshot on a page, if I use the "headless" argument I get this error:

```
    [1127/115120.051:INFO:CONSOLE(157)] "Deprecation warning: moment 
    construction falls back to js Date. 
    This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. 
    Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

        at Function.createFromInputFallback (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:157:187)
at ie (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:157:664)
at De (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:158:1390)
at Me (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:158:1287)
at Se (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:158:1007)
at Ne (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:158:1703)
at Oe (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:158:1737)
at t (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js:154:2701)
at e (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/blackfriday-dialog.dba1b059b906a510ba6c.js:1:580)
at i.<anonymous> (https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/blackfriday-dialog.dba1b059b906a510ba6c.js:1:2029)", source: https://s-new.tradingview.com/static/bundles/vendors.555f7dba06d6ca8b7950.4b2fc7ae22fe.js (157)
```

I'm not sure if the error and the info message are related. 
The same thing happens using phantomJS, but works fine if the chrome window is shown, although that's not an option since every time the screenshot gets taken, chrome steals focus.

here's what I'm trying:

```
         static void Main()
        {
             ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
             options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
             options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
             options.AddArgument("--headless");

             var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

             driver.Url = "https://uk.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=FX:GBPUSD";

             var webElement = driver.FindElementByClassName("chart-widget");
             string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".jpg";
             Byte[] byteArray = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
             System.Drawing.Bitmap screenshot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray));
        }
```

the error happens as the address is being passed to the driver.Url.

Any idea how to fix it or work around it?

Comment: Can you share your code trial?

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?